# GitHub relative link in Markdown file

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is there a way to create a URL anchor, `<a>`, link from within a Markdown file, to another file within the same repository and branch (aka a link relative to the current branch)?

For example, in the master branch I have a README.md file, which I would like do something like:

```
# My Project
is really really cool. My Project has a subdir named myLib, see below.

## myLib documentation
see documentation [here](myLib/README.md)
```

This would allow me to link from one .md to another within the same branch and not have to worry about which branch I'm in (avoid having to do an absolute URL that includes the github.com branch name).

Here is a working example of what I mean:

1. GOTO http://github.com/rynop/testRel, link does not work.
2. GOTO http://github.com/rynop/testRel/blob/master/README.md, link works.

This is expected because at this point the starting URL is in the branch. Now how do I get it to pick up the current branch in the README.md at the root of the repository?

**Update**: I opened an [issue](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/84) against GitHub for this feature request.

Comment: **Finally**: relative links are now supported! I have updated my answer :)

Comment: You can find some solutions in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40422790/relative-link-to-repos-root-from-markdown-file

Comment: And how are relative links supported in restructured text files?

Answer (score 1704, accepted):

Update **30th, January 2013**, 16 months later:

### [GitHub Blog Post **Relative links in markup files**](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files):

> Starting today, **GitHub supports relative links in markup files**.
> Now you can link directly between different documentation files, whether you view the documentation on GitHub itself, or locally, using a different markup renderer.
>
> You want examples of link definitions and how they work? Here's some Markdown for you.
> Instead of an absolute link:
>
> ```
> [a link](https://github.com/user/repo/blob/branch/other_file.md)
> ```
>
> …you can use a relative link:
>
> ```
> [a relative link](other_file.md)
> [a relative link](path%20with%20spaces/other_file.md)
> ```
>
> and we'll make sure it gets linked to `user/repo/blob/branch/other_file.md`.
>
> If you were using a workaround like `[a workaround link](repo/blob/master/other_file.md)`, you'll have to update your documentation to use the new syntax.
>
> This also means **your documentation can now easily stand on its own, without always pointing to GitHub**.

[Marcono1234](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4288506/marcono1234) adds in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file/7658676#comment121919252_7658676)

> Also useful: When the link starts with a `/`, it is relative to the root of the repository (regardless of whether the markdown file is nested in subdirectories)

---

Update December 20th, 2011:

The [GitHub markup issue 84](https://github.com/github/markup/issues/84#issuecomment-3223278) is currently closed by [technoweenie](https://github.com/technoweenie), with the comment:

> We tried adding a `<base>` tag for this, but it causes problems with other relative links on the site.

---

October 12th, 2011:

If you look at the **[raw source of the `README.md`](https://raw.github.com/github/markup/master/README.md)** of Markdown itself(!), relative paths don't seem to be supported.
You will find references like:

```
[r2h]: http://github.com/github/markup/tree/master/lib/github/commands/rest2html
[r2hc]: http://github.com/github/markup/tree/master/lib/github/markups.rb#L13
```

---

As noted in [InvisibleWolf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2229448/invisiblewolf)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46189724/6309), if the target link is a directory and it has space, then you need to use `%20` for each space.

Comment: Hmm.. I can make a relative URL (try [link] someDir/README.md, it will make an anchor) - but I want a github branch aware relative link like: myRepo/tree/<$curBranch>/pathToMd.md. I'll probably just open a feature request with github.com

Comment: @rynop but is your relative path already always using the current branch?

Comment: nope.  See full example here https://github.com/rynop/testRel . I could do a relative link specifying the branch, but that defeats the purpose of what I'm trying to do in the first place.  If i was linking from a .md in one subdir to another, i think it would handle relative link just fine. Problem occurs when linking from .md in root of repo.

Comment: ok so check this. GOTO https://github.com/rynop/testRel, link does not work. GOTO https://github.com/rynop/testRel/blob/master/README.md, link works. This is expected cuz at this point starting URL is in the branch.  Now how do i get it to pick up the current branch in the README.md at the root of the repo?

Comment: @rynop good example, and good question. Time now to contact GitHub support ;)

Comment: thanks. I sent an email to support this morning. Hopefully this is the way to send feat requests as I could not find another way :)

Comment: @rynop: keep us posted by adding your own answer here ;)

Comment: github has not replied to my request - anyone know how to officially request a feature?

Comment: @rynop beside support@github.com (https://github.com/contact), I don't know. And since I presume you already gone that route, maybe adding an issue to the markdon project itself is the way to go: https://github.com/github/markup/issues

Comment: Related: For linking from one wiki page to another, `[Welcome](./wiki/Hello)` works, where Hello is another wiki page in the same repo.

Comment: This works in regular wiki pages, but if you add a _Sidebar.md file there is a difference between how the links resolve on the wiki home page than the rest of the pages. I tried everything here with no luck. The only thing I have come up with so far is to use 2 different _Sidebar.md files and to organize the files into sub-directories.

Comment: @NightOwl888 interesting. Time to contact GitHub support then.

Comment: For images apparently it still does not work. E.g. status badge markdown `[![Actions Status](../../workflows/some-workflow/badge.svg)]` renders an invalid image link: `/user/repo/workflows/some-workflow/badge.svg`.

Comment: @stop-cran Strange, considering https://stackoverflow.com/a/36313391/6309. Did you try with `png` image instead of `svg`?

Comment: @VonC Please disregard my comment - I tried once again and it works as expected: `# Overview [![Actions Status](../../workflows/some-workflow/badge.svg)](../../actions)` shows both the badge and the correct link.

Comment: @stop-cran OK, that looks better indeed.

Comment: It is easy to forget %20 when ' ' is in link(answer of InvisibleWolf). I think that you should add this in your examples because answer where this is mentioned is far from top.

Comment: @LazarĐorđević Good point, thank you. I have updated the answer accordingly.

Comment: Also useful: When the link starts with a `/`, it is relative to the root of the repository (regardless of whether the markdown file is nested in subdirectories).

Comment: @Marcono1234 Thank you for this useful feedback. I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Answer (score 187):

For example, you have a repo like the following:

```
project/
    text.md
    subpro/
       subtext.md
       subsubpro/
           subsubtext.md
       subsubpro2/
           subsubtext2.md
```

The relative link to `subtext.md` in `text.md` might look like this:

```
[this subtext](subpro/subtext.md)
```

The relative link to `subsubtext.md` in `text.md` might look like this:

```
[this subsubtext](subpro/subsubpro/subsubtext.md)
```

The relative link to `subtext.md` in `subsubtext.md` might look like this:

```
[this subtext](../subtext.md)
```

The relative link to `subsubtext2.md` in `subsubtext.md` might look like this:

```
[this subsubtext2](../subsubpro2/subsubtext2.md)
```

The relative link to `text.md` in `subsubtext.md` might look like this:

```
[this text](../../text.md)
```

Comment: One thing I've found, the links are case sensitive, which I did not expect.

Comment: What if there are spaces in my directories?

Comment: @Andy that's a Linux thing, where filenames are case sensitive

Answer (score 40):

GitHub could make this a lot better with minimal work.  Here is a work-around.

I think you want something more like

```
[Your Title](your-project-name/tree/master/your-subfolder)
```

or to point to the README itself

```
[README](your-project-name/blob/master/your-subfolder/README.md)
```

Comment: yep this is what i do today. I don't want to bake in the branch info into the link. It should be relative.

Comment: Is there a way to get at the subfolder using a relative link?

Answer (score 30):

As of January 31, 2013 Github markdown [supports relative links to files](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files).

```
[a relative link](markdown_file.md)
```

However, there are a few deficiencies that have been [discussed in this comment thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7658676/368691).

As an alternative, you can use [Gitdown](https://github.com/gajus/gitdown) to construct [full URLs to the repository](https://github.com/gajus/gitdown#features-gitinfo) and even make them branch aware, e.g.

```
{"gitdown": "gitinfo", "name": "url"} // https://github.com/gajus/gitdown
{"gitdown": "gitinfo", "name": "branch"} // master
```

Gitdown is a GitHub markdown preprocessor. It streamlines common tasks associated with maintaining a documentation page for a GitHub repository, e.g. generating table of contents, including variables, generating URLs and getting information about the repository itself at the time of processing the input. Gitdown seamlessly integrates with your building scripts.

I am the author of the Gitdown library.

Comment: @Thomas Is this part of the Stack Overflow terms of use? If yes, please share a link. I am curious to know the motivation behind such a requirement.

Comment: "Post good, relevant answers, and if some (but not all) happen to be about your product or website, that’s okay. However, you must disclose your affiliation in your answers." http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior

Comment: One would think this falls under the meta information that Stack Overflow is trying to avoid so much, i.e. that promotes an off-topic discussion.

Answer (score 18):

Just wanted to add this because none of the above solutions worked if target link is directory with spaces in it's name. If target link is a directory and it has space then even escaping space with \ doesn't render the link on Github. Only solution worked for me is using `%20` for each space.

e.g.: if directory structure is this

```
Top_dir
|-----README.md
|-----Cur_dir1
      |----Dir A
           |----README.md
      |----Dir B
           |----README.md
```

To make link to `Dir A` in README.md present in `Top_dir` you can do this:

```
[Dir 1](Cur_dir1/Dir%20A)
```

Answer (score 17):

What I found to work for relative folders:

```
[link text](subfolder/subsubfolder/relevantfolder/)
```

where relevant folder is the folder you are trying to link to. The backslash is needed after the folder name. I tried including the project name and tree/main in the path and the other things suggested in previous answers, that lead to a nonexistent page error. The subfolder is a folder within the overall repo project folder.

Thus, file links would be in the form of:

```
[link text](subfolder/subsubfolder/relevantfolder/index.html)
```

If the desired file is not in any folder or subfolder the link is simply:

```
[link text](README.md)
```

for example the README file is not in any subfolders, so that could be the exact relative link you use for the README file.

Answer (score 16):

You can link to file, but not to folders, and keep in mind that, Github will add `/blob/master/` before your relative link(and folders lacks that part so they cannot be linked, neither with HTML `<a>` tags or Markdown link).

So, if we have a file in `myrepo/src/Test.java`, it will have a url like:

```
https://github.com/WesternGun/myrepo/blob/master/src/Test.java
```

And to link it in the readme file, we can use:

```
[This is a link](src/Test.java)
```

or: `<a href="src/Test.java">This is a link</a>`.

(I guess, `master` represents the `master` branch and it differs when the file is in another branch.)

Answer (score 12):

This question is pretty old, but it still seems important, as it isn't easy to put relative references from readme.md to wiki pages on Github.

I played around a little bit and this relative link seems to work pretty well:

`[Your wiki page](../../wiki/your-wiki-page)`

The two `../` will remove `/blob/master/` and use your base as a starting point. I haven't tried this on other repositories than Github, though (there may be compatibility issues).

Comment: that's what I was looking for while trying to have a relative link to issues and pulls. Respectivaly `[issue](../../issues)` & `[Pull Request (PR)](../../pulls)` works!

Answer (score 11):

You can use relative URLs from the root of your repo with `<a href="">`.  Assuming your repo is named `testRel`, put the following in `testRel/README.md`:

```
# My Project
is really really cool. My Project has a subdir named myLib, see below.

## myLib docs
see documentation:
    * <a href="testRel/myLib">myLib/</a>
    * <a href="testRel/myLib/README.md">myLib/README.md</a>
```

Comment: this not valid md syntax

Comment: this may not be valid md syntax, but this helped me other answers did not gave the desired results. kudos!!

Answer (score 9):

In `.md` file when you want to create a link to any related files which is related to same `project folder` or `URL` based links:

1. Existing file link:

> In `.md` file add showing name in `[]` box then open `()` in this box add `/` after that it will auto fetch all existing folders name form which you choose your folder then add '/' it will show inner `file` or 'folders`. This means it will auto fetch the paths and at the end, your URL is created.

Example:

```
[Enter Showing Name](/users/4000266/heysushil)
```

This line show like this:
[Enter Showing Name](/users/4000266/heysushil)

2. Add `URLs` on `.md` file

> Follow the same process only change the `()` box path with `URL` like this:

```
 [HeySushil - YouTube](https://youtube.com/heysushil)
```

This looks like [HeySushil - YouTube](https://youtube.com/heysushil)

> Note: Remember no need to add force manually after adding `/` on `()` box it will auto fetch all existing `folders` and `files`.

Answer (score 6):

I am not sure if I see this option here. You can just create a `/folder` in your repository and use it directly:

```
[a relative link](/folder/myrelativefile.md)
```

No blob or tree or repository name is needed, and it works like a charm.

Comment: You would think that would be the obvious way but it doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 6):

If you want a relative link to your wiki page on GitHub, use this:

```
Read here: [Some other wiki page](path/to/some-other-wiki-page)
```

If you want a link to a file in the repository, let us say, to reference some header file, and the wiki page is at the root of the wiki, use this:

```
Read here: [myheader.h](../tree/master/path/to/myheader.h)
```

The rationale for the last is to skip the "/wiki" path with "../", and go to the master branch in the repository tree without specifying the repository name, that may change in the future.

Answer (score 3):

The behaviour in Github directory links in markdown files could create some headaches.

All files have an url are starting with blob,

```
blob/<branch>/<path>/<fileName>
```

whereas directories have an url starting with tree:

```
tree/<branch>/<path>
```

So no relative link to a directory should work. It points to an url that starts with a **blob**. Magically Github changes some relative path automatically to the **tree** path. Unfortunately not urls containing ".."

I investigate some time to examine the strange behaviour with Github directory links on https://github.com/fluentcodes/GitSamples-GIT/tree/github-readme-links.

Comment: Relative link that contains `../` works only when you are already in a page that has url contains `/blob/`.

Answer (score 2):

Just follow the format below.

```
[TEXT TO SHOW](actual URL to navigate)
```

Comment: It doesn't answer the question, there's no any "relative link" syntax here.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found for relative links in github's `.md` files:

1. Relative links without `../` *(aka. link to file in the same level, or in sub dir)*, seems always work.
2. Relative links that contains `../` works only when you are already in a page whose url contains substring `/blob/`.

   - Otherwise need to use full url that contains `/blob/`, to link.
3. Actually except top level `/README.md`, when view any other files, their url already contains `/blob/`.

   - Thus probably you can always use relative links that contains `../` in files, except `/README.md`.
   - But `/README.md` is in top level, thus it shouldn't need a relative link that contains `../`.
   - So, you should never need a full path link *(that contains github domain)* to link to files in the same github repo.

---

### Example (links among multiple language doc)

- In `/README.md`, can use relative links without `../`.

  ```
  [中文](doc/cn/README.md) |
  [日本語](doc/jp/README.md)
  ```
- In `/doc/cn/README.md`, since when we view it, the url already contains `/blob/`, thus could use relative links with `../`.

  ```
  [English](../../README.md) |
  [日本語](../jp/README.md)
  ```

*(**BTW**, the example come from this [git-merge-flow](https://github.com/kuchaguangjie/git-merge-flow) repo.)*

Answer (score 0):

You can also insert your links (relative or absolute) at the bottom to reduce clutter in text.
It can also be a good option for repetitive links.

```markdown
This is [my linked text].

  [my linked text]: relative/path/in/repo/to/file.txt "Optional title for mouse hover"
```

This is [my linked text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file#7658676).

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it's useful inside arrays with many links !