# Is it possible to make relative link to image in a markdown file in a gist?

Tags: github, markdown, gist

I've got a gist which contains a markdown file and an image.

Is there a way to do a relative link to this image?
Something like `![My image](image.png)` instead of `![My image](https://gist.github.com/user/605560c2961cb3025038/raw/b75d2...6e8/img.png)`

Here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/alienlebarge/605560c2961cb3025038)

Answer (score 234, accepted):

As of now, relative image links are working for me, in both a repository and a wiki.  I'm using syntax like this:

```
![Kiku](images/Kiku.jpg)
```

Here's an example:

https://github.com/mark-anders/relative-image-url

Comment: thanks! I was frustrated trying to use local images but this worked!

Comment: My mistake was having a space between the `]` and `(`

Comment: At least for Github, I just found out that you cannot have spaces in your file names, or GitHub cannot recognize local images (I am not sure adding quotes will solve this though)

Comment: This may work on regular Github repos, but doesn't on Gists (https://gist.github.com).

Comment: I found that you cannot have any folder depth on a gist but if everything is root level then you can have multiple files in a gist. The web UI doesn't allow you to upload anything other than text, but if you pull down the gist repo locally you can commit it. I found if you have 2FA on your account you'll need to generate a personal access token: https://github.com/settings/tokens. Unfortunately it will generate a path that you cannot have locally, so you have to upload them and then use an absolute path to the image.

Comment: If there are special characters on the relative path of the image you're trying to link, make sure it is url encoded.

Comment: @XiaoyongZhu, if you have spaces in your file name, follow @felixperreault's advice and url-encode the file name - i.e. replace the space with `%20`.

Comment: It's also case-sensitive (including extension), just in case anyone else falls in the same trap as I did.

Answer (score 6):

According to http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/35-Including-Data-From-Github.html, the problem in using
    https://gist.github.com/user/605560c2961cb3025038/raw/b75d2...6e8/img.png

is that the `b75d2...6e8` part varies per file (a quick experimentation confirms it is the git blob id).  However you can drop that part resulting in a URL pointing to the latest version:

```
https://gist.github.com/user/605560c2961cb3025038/raw/img.png
```

or to take a working example:

```
https://gist.githubusercontent.com/cben/46d9536baacb7c5d196c/raw/dodgetocat_v2.png
```

#### Relative path?

This also works as relative path `raw/dodgetocat_v2.png`!
However (as of late 2017) github can render the same gist from 2 URLs:

- When viewed from https://gist.github.com/cben/46d9536baacb7c5d196c/ (with trailing slash), the relative path is appended, resolves to https://gist.github.com/cben/46d9536baacb7c5d196c/raw/dodgetocat_v2.png — works :-)
- When viewed from https://gist.github.com/cben/46d9536baacb7c5d196c (no trailing slash), the relative path replaces the last part of the URL, resolves to https://gist.github.com/cben/raw/dodgetocat_v2.png — broken :-(

[UPDATED Dec 2017.  Previous problems of raw files served as `Content-Type: application/octet-stream` and rewriting `src` attributes of images to `camo.githubusercontent.com` no longer happen, at least not for images from same gist.]

**Alas, we can't just use the first URL and trust it to always work.**

- Currently neither form returns a redirect, nor serves a rel=canonical link.  I wouldn't bet on Github to never change this!
- All internal gist links (e.g. from user's page https://gist.github.com/cben/) omit the trailing slash :-(
- Gists in Google search results omit the trailing slash :-(

(You could use relative path `46d9536baacb7c5d196c/raw/dodgetocat_v2.png` that would only work *without* trailing slash, but that's also questionable idea, and less worth it — not really more flexible than full URL.)

#### Using a proxy?

Both can be worked around with a proxy fixing the Content-Type, e.g. Rawgit or Bl.ocks.org (not by Github, don't abuse them).  Unfortunately Rawgit doesn't render Markdown, only serves files as-is, and Bl.ocks.org does render markdown but the URL structure is such that relative links won't work.  This means you can either reference full external URL in Markdown, or relative in HTML :-(

See https://gist.github.com/cben/46d9536baacb7c5d196c/ forked off your gist,
and its index.html viewed via:

- http://rawgit.com/cben/46d9536baacb7c5d196c/raw/index.html
- http://rawgit.com/cben/46d9536baacb7c5d196c/raw/
- http://bl.ocks.org/cben/raw/46d9536baacb7c5d196c
- http://bl.ocks.org/cben/46d9536baacb7c5d196c

Comment: It's not pretty but you can always put a hardcoded link at the top of the markdown doc that tells the reader to view the document at the link with the trailing slash, like `[view the doc here for working images](https://gist.github.com/user/605560c2961cb3025038/)`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the relative link is working for me. I am using pancake.io to host my pages.
http://pancake.io/2c8aa8/topics/cpp/cpp.md

The images on that page are in the `cpp` folder.

The markdown code used for the first image is

```
![C++ Var Types](basic_cpp_var_types.png)
```

The markdown code (actually html) used for the second image is

```
<div style='float: center'>
  <img style='width: 600px' src="prefixpostfixincrement.png"></img>
</div>
```

*NOTE: I missed the gist part. Try the html way if gist doesn't support the markdown relative image path syntax.*

Comment: The HTML way doesn't work. It's more a problem of Gist than Markdown

Answer (score 3):

tested just now...
i was unable to use relative urls on the github wiki.

i had to add the image to the wiki repo, then browser the repo and have github show it to me (so i could grab the url). then use the full url in the markdown. but luckily, the urls are simple to predict: `https://github.com/*username*/*reponame*/wiki/*imagename.png*`

i submitted this isse to the github support.

Answer (score 1):

No, the relative URL to an image from markdown doesn’t work, so you’ll have to stick with the long, static URL:

https://gist.github.com/mattborn/c346c8689a5eaf86e823

However, relative URLs to some files work:

http://bl.ocks.org/mattborn/c346c8689a5eaf86e823

Answer (score 1):

After scratching my head around this for good 15 minutes I realized:

Relative paths to images do work, but when you're writing a markdown file directly from the github web app, the images don't show up in preview. Once you commit the file the images are visible as expected