# Adding Images in Azure DevOps Wiki

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-wiki

I'm trying to add a few images to the wiki in 1 of my Azure DevOps projects. When I use the absolute path as mentioned here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#images in the article, the images are not showing up. Any help?

Comment: I ended here trying to resolve images in devops repos / local machine README.md with the same source. Obvious when you figure it out though: Use relative paths e.g. ![AR-Architectural](./AR-architectural.png)   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764242/is-it-possible-to-make-relative-link-to-image-in-a-markdown-file-in-a-gist

Answer (score 88):

The wiki pages get created in their own Git repository and the image files are also added there. You can browse the repos from within DevOps at; `https://dev.azure.com/MyOrganisation/MyProject/_git/MyProject.wiki`

The markdown path for the image should begin `/.attachments/` and make sure if you are adding dimension you use `=500x` and not `=500` if you exclude the height e.g.

```
![MyImage.png](/.attachments/MyImage-98765432-abcd-1234-abcd-a1234567890b.png =500x)
```

Comment: replace all %20(space) from the link by -(dash)
example:
...com/MyOrganisation/My%20Project%20Name/_git/My-Project-Name.wiki

Comment: Trying to mass export Confluence spaces here, discovered that you also CAN'T nest images in e.g. `/.attachments/sub1/image.jpg`, it has to be flat in that top, e.g. `/.attachments/image.jpg`. I wonder why this is so restrictive?

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for image resizing.

Comment: If you paste the image, it won't show until you click save.

Answer (score 27):

**Add image from local machine:**
In the wiki page editor, click 'Insert a file' icon and select image from your local pc, you will see mark-up something like: `![image.jpg](/.attachment/image-devOpsfileIdentifyer-withMixedAlphabetsAndDigits.jpg)`

This will also displays preview in the editor.

Answer (score 12):

Actually, you can now use the "Insert a file" button (represented by a paperclip icon) when editing a wiki page to upload an image.

When you upload an image this way, the image is automatically stored in the "/.attachments/" folder

Comment: This is very similar to [an existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58343475/3025856) from last year. In the future, please review existing answers and upvote ones that are useful before contributing a new answer. If an existing answer is mostly right, but includes a minor error, you can even edit it to suggest a correction.

Answer (score 9):

For my side I just copy the image in the clipboard and after that on paste it generate automatically the markdown code

**TLDR**

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> and <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

Comment: The best for me.  No additional external resources required.

Answer (score 4):

When inserting a file in a Wiki, you initially get an image-url like `blob:https://dev.azure.com/SOME-GUID`. This url (when including the `blob:`-prefix, can be used to display the attached image in an `img`-tag.

```
<img src="blob:https://dev.azure.com/SOME-GUID" />
```

[image: Centered image in Azure DevOps Wiki]

If the image is important enough to be inside a Wiki page, it's probably important enough to host it somewhere you can use it inside your wiki. Have a look at creating a [public container/blob in an Azure Storage account](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-manage-access-to-resources).

**EDIT:**
For your specific image: right-click the image and select `Copy image address`. You'll get an URL like this that you can use as the `src` of the `img`-tag.

`https://dev.azure.com/rubdevopson/c53ed56f-c130-470b-a6ae-3c4a93266530/_apis/git/repositories/88df06c2-f627-4953-9438-0f762d4cad3a/Items?path=%2FPartsUnlimited_docs%2Fhome.png&versionDescriptor%5BversionOptions%5D=0&versionDescriptor%5BversionType%5D=0&versionDescriptor%5Bversion%5D=master&download=false&resolveLfs=true&%24format=octetStream&api-version=5.0-preview.1`

Comment: Yes that's correct, but what if I have the images under the same repo? I have a bunch of documents structured within the repo as folders. So all my images are under that folder. How do I use in that case? Here is the link to see how does the repo look like with images which I'm trying to access inside wiki page: https://dev.azure.com/rubdevopson/_git/AzureDevOps?path=%2FPartsUnlimited_docs%2Fhome.png&version=GBmaster

Comment: Yes, I know that option. I was trying out to use the relative path to see how it supports or works :-)

Comment: Would be nice if the GUIDs could be replaced by human-editable names

Comment: Definitely find another place to host the image because ADO deletes the image in less than a day, presumably because it can't see the markdown for the image.  It will look right to the author for a little while since the browser caches the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can host external images in the **Azure DevOps** wiki, using the following syntax:
`![Your image](https://some-location/your-image.jpg)`

The image will need to be hosted via **https**, http will not work.

*Reference:*
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/wiki/markdown-guidance?view=azure-devops#images