# unable to view image in the github readme file preview

Tags: github, readme

I am unable to view image in the preview of the readme file on github.
I have created a folder "pics" and readme has following line:

```
![Image-1](pics/img-1.png)
```

but unable to get a link for the relative path, instead its just plain text, so image doesnt occur in prview

Answer (score 2):

That seems to work, as illustrated in [`mark-anders/relative-image-url`](https://github.com/mark-anders/relative-image-url)

Check in your case if you have a case issue (`pics` instead of `Pics`, or `img-1.png` instead of `img-1.PNG`), as [commented here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15764242/is-it-possible-to-make-relative-link-to-image-in-a-markdown-file-in-a-gist#comment118419707_36313391).

Comment: You are the best, this was the solution