# GitHub flavored markdown for non http scheme links

Tags: markdown, github-flavored-markdown

Is it possible to create a link to a scheme other than http://

For example, I'm trying to create a link for an Adblocker filter. I was hoping this would work but it doesn't

```
[Subscribe](abp:subscribe?location=http%3A%2F%2Fraw2.github.com%2Filyakatz%2Fadblock_filters%2Fmaster%2Finpage_popups.txt&amp;title=Inpage%20popups%20filter)
```

Is it even possible to do? If so, how?

Thanks

Comment: I guess you meant to write "GitHub" in the title.

Comment: possible duplicate of [github relative link in markdown file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `https://subscribe.adblockplus.org/` instead of `abp:subscribe`:

`[subscribe](https://subscribe.adblockplus.org/?location=http%3A%2F%2Fraw2.github.com%2Filyakatz%2Fadblock_filters%2Fmaster%2Finpage_popups.txt&title=Inpage%20popups%20filter)`

Also it works here, on StackOverflow: [subscribe](https://subscribe.adblockplus.org/?location=http%3A%2F%2Fraw2.github.com%2Filyakatz%2Fadblock_filters%2Fmaster%2Finpage_popups.txt&title=Inpage%20popups%20filter).

By the way, your link is broken - the correct one is https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ilyakatz/adblock_filters/master/inpage_popups.txt

Comment: This works for the specific example in the question, but does not answer the generic question about non-http link protocol. How would I get say OneNote to open the link, instead of the browser? Normally this can be done with a `onenote:` prefix to the link. Can you do that in markdown?

Answer (score 0):

If someone is still looking for an answer, I just created this really simple redirector tool that can solve this exact issue I was having, if anyone still encounters it : https://github.com/intradeus/http-protocol-redirector

It works by taking any string at a query parameter and redirects the website to that string. It transforms your protocol URL (that Stackoverflow, Github, Slack or any markdown platform cannot view as an hyperlink) into https.
Plus it's **literally** 2 lines of code, you can check it out.

Use it like so :
https://intradeus.github.io/http-protocol-redirector?r=<your protocol:/URL>

Ex:

- Link without it vscode://ms-vscode.remote-repositories/open?url=https://github.com/intradeus/http-protocol-redirector
- Link with it : https://intradeus.github.io/http-protocol-redirector?r=vscode://ms-vscode.remote-repositories/open?url=https://github.com/intradeus/http-protocol-redirector

Comment: Please don't just post some tool or library as an answer. At least demonstrate [how it solves the problem](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605) in the answer itself.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, added an explanation. But it has to be a tool since Github said they won't accept non-http protocols as hyperlinks.