# How to link to the top-level directory of a GitHub repository

Tags: github, github-flavored-markdown

Suppose I am writing a `README.md` file for a subdirectory in a GitHub repository using GitHub-flavored Markdown.  How can I can construct a link that goes to the top-level directory of my repository, while preserving the branch or commit that the user is currently viewing, and not requiring me to hardcode the name or owner of the repository?

[Relatives links in READMEs](https://help.github.com/articles/relative-links-in-readmes/) are supposed to work on GitHub, and they do work for most files and directories in a repository, but I can't figure out how to link to the top-level directory of a repository.

I have a file in my [test repository](https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/test_github) named `subdir/README.md` where I tried putting the following relative links:

```
[link to ../](../) - does not work

[link to ..](..) - does not work

[link to ./..](./..) - does not work
```

However, when these links are rendered, they all go to a single URL like https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/test_github/blob/master which returns a 404 page instead of redirecting to https://github.com/DavidEGrayson/test_github/tree/master.

I really want to be able to link to the top level of a repository because *that is where the Download button is*.  So, how can I do it?

Comment: If I remember correctly your file tree is under `/test_github` but all your wiki/README files are under `/test_github/blob/master`. So from your README file the relative path to access your root folder would be `../../`

Comment: https://github.com/gabrieloshiro/github-markdown-playground

Comment: Gabriel: Thanks, I might have to do it that way, but I was hoping for something better because when I am visiting https://github.com/gabrieloshiro/github-markdown-playground/blob/1c378d5/README.md and click on your first link, the URL loses the commit number and just goes to display the HEAD commit.

Comment: Ohhhhh I see now....

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file ?

Comment: Doesn't answer my question.

Comment: :-( sorry... good question though...

Comment: You just need to provide filename and it seems a trick with "../" works as you need, eg:

`Make sure to read [main README](../README.md) first, pls.`

But I'm not able to link the main folder though. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

like this.

```
<a href="../../tree/master">link to top</a>
```