# Relative Links in Github pages not working still?

Tags: github, jekyll, relative-path

I have a Github repo where the readme.md has relative links to display images from a folder called img.

```
![Add Remove Programs](/img/ArcGIS_Pro_DI_LicenseCheck.jpg?raw=true "Add Remove Programs")
```

This displays fine at [the project address](https://github.com/simongis/gnaf-for-arcgis).

But on the Github page, [the links are broken](https://simongis.github.io/gnaf-for-arcgis/).  They are trying to reference the following URL, without the project name:

https://simongis.github.io/img/ArcGIS_Pro_DI_LicenseCheck.jpg  = 404

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file) and [this blog post](https://github.com/blog/1395-relative-links-in-markup-files), I thought this issue has been resolved?

Can someone point out where I am going wrong?

I have tried playing around setting the baseurl to my project director in the _config.yml but that did not seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 1):

That is exactly what *baseurl* solves:

> Base URL
>
> Serve the website from the given base URL

Set it with the project name and make sure you generate the links in your website including it , for example with the *absolute_url* filter

```
baseurl: /gnaf-for-arcgis

![Add Remove Programs]({{'/img/ArcGIS_Pro_DI_LicenseCheck.jpg?raw=true' | absolute_url}} "Add Remove Programs")
```