# How to add a relative link to a file in a submodule in github markdown?

Tags: github, markdown, github-flavored-markdown

I'm using markdown for the README file in my repositories.

Relative links work well for files in the same repo.

But I want to link a file in a submodule (so that the same version as the submodule is displayed).

The usecase is the following: I have a submodule in `external/fancy-lib`. In the README.md of my repository I want to add `"please refer to fancy-lib's [README](external/fancy-lib/README.md) for info about the required packages"`, but it generates a non-existent link.

Adding a link to fancy-lib's README from fancy-lib's repository (i.e. `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<account>/<repo>/README.md`) would point to HEAD which is not always the same version included in my repository.
On the other hand, manually updating the link (i.e. the `<hash>` in  `https://github.com/<account>/<repo>/blob/<hash>/README.md`) each time the submodule is updated to a new version (git pull) is a burden of maintenance.

Any workaround?

Comment: You can try doing normal `[link](../external/fancy-lib/README.md)` but I'm not sure it works for submodules.

Comment: I assumed external directory is one level above for some reason, if it's not, you don't need the `..` at all. Also check: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I do not think relative links are going to work. One can always use the full URL though, which is something like

```
![](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/<account>/<name of submodule repo>/README.md)
```

or

```
https://github.com/<account>/<repo>/blob/<hash>/README.md
```

Comment: I explicitly mentioned *relative* because I want to avoid this.

Comment: Btw, since the submodule points to a specific version, the full URL is something like: `https://github.com/<account>/<repo>/blob/<hash>/README.md`