# Add image with link in Github's README.md?

Tags: github, markdown, readme

How to add an image that is also a link to an external page on  Github's README.md?

Adding a markdown to display an image is pretty simple (answer at [Add images to README.md on GitHub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14494747/add-images-to-readme-md-on-github)). Adding a link is also pretty simple ([GitHub relative link in Markdown file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file)), but it seems there's is no way to add an image that is also a link to an external site.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com/"><img src="RELATIVE_PATH_TO_IMAGE></img></a>
```

Answer (score 98):

Try simply the syntax:

- 2020: `[![name](link to image on GH)](link to your URL)`
- 2023: `[<img src="path/to/image.png">](https://link-to-your-URL/)`,
  see my [`README`](https://github.com/VonC/conmode/blob/a932f85f2ff2ceff51c59227063a0d34294980df/README.md) as an example, from [commit a932f85](https://github.com/VonC/conmode/commit/a932f85f2ff2ceff51c59227063a0d34294980df).
  Syntax from [DaCuteRaccoon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17585064/dacuteraccoon)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73759210/6309).

That will wrap the image as a link

Comment: This doesn't work for me in my readme.md in github. Do I need to configure something in settings?

Comment: @Rod No, no configuration needed. Is there another syntax from this page which would work for you?

Comment: I don't get it then, 88 upvotes seems to me it work for them. I am thinking of the right area, right GitHub readme.md

Comment: Not working for me in GitHub Discussions. No matter if I try the above, or using plan `<a>` and `<img>`, GitHub always makes it link to the image in a new tab, and it never links to my link.

Comment: @trusktr I have updated the answer with the current syntax, and added an example from an actual GitHub repository.

Answer (score 9):

Some additional syntax mixing html and markdown, giving you more flexibility in adjusting how image is displayed.

Assuming you have repo structure as follows (it just refers to relative link used in syntax below):

[example repo structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k9ZWK.png)

you can use

```
[<img alt="alt_text" width="40px" src="images/image.PNG" />](https://www.google.com/)
```

Answer (score 6):

Structure:

```
[![name](link to image on GH)](link to your URL)
```

Example:

```
![image search api](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/110724391/184472398-c590b47c-e1f2-41f8-87e6-2a1f68e8850d.png)[(Youtube)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3HIr0imLgxM)
```

Answer (score 6):

The people who wrote the previous answers were overcomplicating it. This works in Markdown+HTML5 and is easy to understand when looking at the source code.

The code: `[<img src="img/myImage.png">](http://example.com/)`,

where `img/myImage.png` should be replaced by the relative path to your image, and `http://example.com/` should be replaced by the link you want to visit when the image is clicked.

Comment: Yes, this is much easier to follow, thanks! It also helped solve an issue, where the images weren't clickable on some browsers.