# Github Markdown Readme.md, add image from url, with hyperlink

Tags: github, markdown

So I am trying to add a image, specifically LinkedIn icon, which contains a hyperlink to my linkedin profile URL. Based on this previous question [Add image with link in Github's README.md?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61071158/add-image-with-link-in-githubs-readme-md), I tried the following syntax:

```
[![text](https://img.shields.io/badge/LinkedIn-0077B5?style=for-the-badge&logo=linkedin&logoColor=white)](www.linkedin.com/in/myprofile)
```

The image shows up fine, but clicking on it does not go to "www.linkedin.com/in/myprofile", instead it redirects to "https://github.com/myuser/blob/main/www.linkedin.com/in/myprofile". How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so it seems we must include "https://", otherwise the link won't work. So:

```
[![text](https://img.shields.io/badge/LinkedIn-0077B5?style=for-the-badge&logo=linkedin&logoColor=white)](https://www.linkedin.com/in/myprofile)
```