# How can I create a link from my github README.md to some static html in the repository?

Tags: github, r-markdown

I want the link to resolve as a web page, not as a github source of a web page.

Comment: Could you please elaborate your problem? I am confused on whether you want to redirect to a URL or what.

Answer (score 0):

check out [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file)

They suggest trying

```
[a link](https://github.com/user/repo/blob/branch/other_file.md)
```

but without screenshots or examples, we don't know exactly what you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 0):

Use the https://htmlpreview.github.io/ feature by appending the link to your static page in the repo to that link and make a reference to the whole link in your readme. For example:

https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/name/repo/master/doc/index.html