# Github readme.md preview rendered html inside the repository

Tags: html, github, web, markdown, readme

As the bellow figure shown, when I click the 'link' in the readme.md, It will open the './doc/demo.html' source-code webpage, while I want to open that in rendered html, e.g., open it in new tab in browser(chrome)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: You may like to try this without the initial \. Take a look at this questions accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file/ (*Also useful: When the link starts with a /, it is relative to the root of the repository (regardless of whether the markdown file is nested in subdirectories)*). Still I'm not really sure you can actually render an html like you're trying to. The best and easy way you can do this is simply upload the html to any free host and make the link to your page :)

Comment: 1/5: I tried bellow path of "/doc/demo.html", "doc/demo.html" and "./doc/demo.html", they all open the html source instead of preview/rendered webpage. 2/5: It seems github takes .html as "programming" instead of "document". 3/5 when I tested another type file of "/doc/demo.md", github opens it in preview/rendered format. 4/5: My current solution is to use https://htmlpreview.github.io/ to get the preview page. 5/5 later maybe I will put my webpage on a host/server as alternative solution