# Not able to see link in VSCode while writing markdown?

Tags: github, visual-studio-code

[image]

I am not able to see the link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [GitHub relative link in Markdown file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7653483/github-relative-link-in-markdown-file)

Comment: remove the space in the link or use `&#20;`

Answer (score 1):

This isn't specific to VSCode. Spaces may not appear in URLs, so your markdown is interpreted as literal characters, not the a link.

You need to encode the space as a `+` or `%20`:

```
[here](Day+1/day1.md)
[here](Day%201/day1.md)
```